# Need to make html field ID dynamic for drop down options using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend, dynamic-programming

I am trying to make a search UI, where I am using Keys and Values for making an API call to backend.

These key value fields are dynamic - there is a button that adds extra field.

Now these, field depending on the key selected will have drop down on the value side...

I was able to create a logic for it but it is taking it for all the previous fields as well and not the current only.

I am seeing that the function works for the previous key value fields as well ( meaning when I add more filters - key value fields using a button, the last key value field whichever I will select on the key side will then the function will work for the above key value field as well, I ll add a photo for explanation)

I was looking for a solution to overcome this to keeping it to the latest key value fields only. ( I am thinking of using html id dynamic here for solution)

When I select Car or Phone the drop down should appear on the right,
add filter adds key value fields below..

I add multiple key value fields, the last key which I select will also make value side drop down to its above fields as well....

To change this I am thinking of using id = advanced-filter-2 as dynamic... I need solution for this as I am a beginner.

js fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/3wb8sq96/

```js
function Getoptions(e) {
  // $("#advancedFilter+1").change(function (e) {
  var opt = e.value;
  if (opt == "Color" || opt == "Phone") {
    $("#advanced-filter-2").append("<option value='Green'></option>");
    $("#advanced-filter-2").append("<option value='Yellow'></option>");
    $("#advanced-filter-2").append("<option value='Red'></option>");
    $("#advanced-filter-2").append("<option value='Orange'></option>");
  } else {
    $("#advanced-filter-2").empty();
  }
  // });
}

var filterCount = 1;

$(".removeFilter").toggle(filterCount > 1); //toggling appearance of removefilter button on condition


//Function to replicate fields in the form
function replicateFields(inputClass, anchorClass, i) {
  // debugger;
  var elementToReplicate = $(inputClass).first(), //Only clone first group of inputs
    clonedElement = elementToReplicate.clone(); //Cloned the element
  clonedElement.find("input").val(""); //Clear cloned elements value on each new addition
  clonedElement.find("input").each(function() {
    this.name = this.name;
  });
  clonedElement.insertBefore($(anchorClass));
}

//Calling function on click
$(".addFilter").click(function() {
  replicateFields(".filterInputs", ".addFilter", filterCount++);
  //console.log(filterCount);
  $(".removeFilter").toggle(filterCount > 1);
});

// Function to remove added filter in the form
function removeFields(inputClass, anchorClass, i) {
  // debugger;
  var elementToRemove = $(inputClass).last(), //Only remove last group of inputs
    removedElement = elementToRemove.remove(); //Removed the element
  removedElement.remove($(anchorClass));
}

//Calling function on click
$(".removeFilter").click(function() {
  removeFields(".filterInputs", ".removeFilter", filterCount--);
  //console.log(filterCount);
  $(".removeFilter").toggle(filterCount > 1); //toggling appearance of removefilter button on condition
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h2 class="card-title">Search</h2>
<form id="search" action="/service/table/search/" method="post">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="filterInputs col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" name="filterKey[]" id="advancedFilter" list="advanced-filter-1" onchange="Getoptions(this);" />
      <datalist id="advanced-filter-1">
          <option value="Color"></option>
          <option value="Car"></option>
          <option value="Phone"></option>
        </datalist>
      <input type="text" name="filterValue[]" list="advanced-filter-2" />
      <datalist id="advanced-filter-2">
        </datalist>
    </div>
    <a href="#!" class="addFilter col-sm-2 col-form-label">Add Filter</a>
    <a href="#!" style="text-align: center" class="removeFilter col-sm-2 col-form-label">Remove Filter</a
      >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: pls share the https://jsfiddle.net/ so it would be easy to answer

Comment: Run code snippet was working same but yes I will add it now

Comment: I have added js fiddle link, lmk if you can help. Thanks